# Who posts these?

Tags: support

[image: 1]

I'd just like to know because I've seen those on new posts in my review queue attached to kind of "borderline" posts. If the fact that the pre-formatted paragraph is there indicates that a mod has already seen the post, I would be less inclined to flag the post. However, if those are automatically generated by the system, then a flag may be appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Moderators do.

[image]

These "post notices" can be added to any post. The one you've observed is generally used when a post isn't *quite* bad enough to be immediately deleted, but is clearly borderline and may need a fair bit of work to be useful.

Comment: Good to know. If a mod has already seen the borderline post, I see no reason to flag unless I really have a burr up my butt about it. Thanks.

Comment: @Jolenealaska One thing to keep in mind is that we'll generally try to take the minimal sufficient action, e.g. a post notice instead of protecting the question. It's possible that'll turn out not to be enough, so if you see a question that looks like it's still getting a lot of bad answers even with the post notice, feel free to flag.